# Checking if a .json file is empty in Python gives me JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, if-statement

I'm currently working on another school project where I have to write to a .json file. As it depends on if the file is empty or not, I have a simple if clause in my code which handles this:

```
json_start = {"messages": []}

with open(self._db, 'r') as json_file:
    first_char = json_file.read(1)
    if not first_char:
        json_content = json_start
        last_id = 0
    else:
        json_content = json.load(json_file)
        message_list = json_content.get("messages")
        last_id = message_list[-1].get("id")
```

As you can see, I read the first char of `json_file` to decide if the file is empty or not, and when it's not, I load the contents of the file into `json_content` with `json.load(json_file)`. When the file is empty, everything works accordingly.

However, if my file has content in it, like this:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "header": "Subj 1",
            "body": "body 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

For some odd reason I get an `JSONDecodeError: Extra data`. I've checked if there aren't any whitespaces in the file where they shouldn't be, and there's nothing to be found.

Just why do I get this error?

Comment: Why not just use `try ... catch` and catch all errors when Json parsing empty file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `json_file.read(1)`, `json.load()` will start reading from the second character of the file, which will be invalid. You should rewind back to the beginning of the file.

```
with open(self._db, 'r') as json_file:
    first_char = json_file.read(1)
    if not first_char:
        json_content = json_start
        last_id = 0
    else:
        json_file.seek(0)
        json_content = json.load(json_file)
        message_list = json_content.get("messages")
        last_id = message_list[-1].get("id")
```

Comment: I really suggest to just using `try ... catch` and catch any error loading the Json file (not read/seek etc.)

Comment: I thought of suggesting that, but maybe they want to distinguish an empty file (which is normal when the application runs the first time) from some other JSON error.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted! I'll definitely look into try...catch, though the reason I didn't want to use it was that I heard it was "sloppy" programming.